# How do you run a GUI application without GUI (gui application as daemon on headless server)?

Tags: xorg, gui, headless

Okay, so I want to run a GUI application as daemon on a server without X. The application is a java program. It can be configured in a configuration file so the GUI is not necessary to use it. Unfortunately it doesn't have a shell executable.

I knew that one once, but forgot the solution. Basically there is a program which fakes an X-server to other programs. Finding that would be the ideal solution. Just can't remember what it was called.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are referring to xvfb - the ability to run in a framebuffer.

[image: Download] or `sudo apt-get install xvfb`

You need to specify a resolution and colour depth as well as the nominal display number

Usage:

```
xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x8 &
export DISPLAY=":1"
java application_name.jar
```

or shorter:

```
xvfb-run -a -e /tmp/some/log/file.log java -jar /home/user/somejava.jar
```

`-a` chooses a display number automatically, `-e file` specifies a logfile for error messages.